# изменение сумму в зависимости от checkbox

Tags: php, html, css

Как сделать чтобы при нажатии на checkbox уменьшалась цифра в div и оставалось такой даже если отправили информацию по кнопке для других пользователей

```html
<h1>Опрос</h1>
<form id="form">
  <div class="form-control">
    <label for="name" id="label-name">
            </label>
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="ФИО" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-control">
    <label for="text" id="label-email">
            </label>
    <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Направление" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-control">
    <label for="inp-1" class="text-ex-space">
        <div id="volebol">Мест 8</div>
                <input type="checkbox"
                    name="inp">Волейбол</input></label>
    <label for="inp-2">
                <input type="checkbox"
                    name="inp">Мини Футбол</input></label>
    <label for="inp-3">
                <input type="checkbox"
                    name="inp">Перетягивание каната</input></label>
    <label for="inp-4">
                <input type="checkbox"
                    name="inp">Стритбол</input></label>
    <label for="inp-5">
                <input type="checkbox"
                    name="inp">Гиревой спорт</input></label>
    <label for="inp-6">
                <input type="checkbox"
                    name="inp">Легкая атлетика</input></label>
    <label for="inp-7">
                <input type="checkbox"
                    name="inp">Армспорт</input></label>
    <label for="inp-7">
                <input type="checkbox"
                    name="inp">Силовое троеборье</input></label>
    <label for="inp-7">
                <input type="checkbox"
                    name="inp">Шахматы</input></label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" value="submit">
            Готово
        </button>
</form>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: можете привести рабочий кусок кода со всеми инпутами, и что это за label ? Все чекбоксы так и обернуты в него 1 вместе с цифрой мест? И что имеете ввиду под "оставалось такой даже если отправили информацию по кнопке для других пользователей"

Comment: ну сайт будет хостится когда человек будет нажимать на checbox число будет уменьшаться чтобы было видно сколько мест осталось и отправит по кнопке на email вот эту всю информацию которую тут ввёл и нажал и нужно чтобы когда следующий человек зашёл чтобы он видел уже не 8 мест а 7 просто нужно с факультета собирать людей на мероприятия и чтобы вот так каждый раз не разбираться кто идёт а кто нет когда мест ограничено а люди с разных направлений или может вообще этим не заморачиваться и подскажете что-то?

Comment: чтобы сохранять количество мест - нужен бэкенд, одного фронтенда недостаточно. И это зависит от вашего сайта - для простенького лендинга достаточно ajax+php чтобы сохранять хотя бы в файле, а так же потом брать из него каждый раз для актуализации данных.